# SIMD instructions used in assembly listing

Tags: assembly, compilation, simd, instructions

If the following compilation option is used

```
–O3 –mtune=barcelona –msse4.2 –fprefetch-loop-arrays
```

How to know from assembly listing that the SIMD instructions are used ?

Comment: Well if you see any, then they're being used?

Comment: AFAIK barcelonas do not have SSE 4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working on Linux (or similar), you can use `objdump` to examine the assembler of your object file or executable.  You can then examine it for instances of [SIMD instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#SIMD_instructions).